# What does *Notice added Current event by called2voyage♦* mean?

Tags: discussion

This is my [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/mars-pictures-taken-by-mom) that I posted in space.spaceexchange.com and when I go to [edited](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/5440/revisions) then 
 I see the following

```
Notice added Current event by called2voyage♦
```

I want to know what does this mean

Also right below the above line I can see another line

```
 Tweeted twitter.com/#!/StackSpaceExp/status/515126665291509761
```

I want to know who tweets this and how is it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Called2Voyage's addition of a post notice that the *post is related to a rapidly changing event* is formally correct. ISRO's Mars Orbiter Mission (MOM) barely entered Mars' orbit at the time you asked the question, with new and relevant to your question information and requested resources coming in all the time. Such post notice is supposed to inform readers that information presented in some still fresh answers might already be outdated. This is necessary to prevent disputes over which answer is better and more helpful, and readers should take notice of when they were posted. Without that notice, your question wouldn't really be suitable for our Q&A, because we expect answers to be relevant for longer than perhaps a day or so.

Pericynthion's answer already has one downvote, even though it was factually correct at the time of writing / posting it. This is not what "reward" we have in mind for our members that took the time and bothered to write an answer that might have been helpful only a short while ago. Sometimes, answers will *give it a best shot*, and that might not prove as exactly true at a later date, but downvoting without comment might seem hostile. And that (dog eat dog) is not what sort of a community we're trying to run here.

As for the notification that the post was tweeted by [our Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackSpaceExp), well have a look at it and you'll notice that most of our site's activities are shared (or perhaps *advertized* is a better word) via social networks to improve our visibility. These tweets are automated and done by the system as soon as the reviews on posts indicate there's nothing strikingly wrong with them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Do you think the 2nd para is necessary to be included here(I dont think the 2nd para has any link to my question above) and How long that line(*Post is related to a rapidly changing event.*) will stay there